# Can't programmatically change UILabel text after viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a routine in my iOS program that imports and manipulates a file from Dropbox. This can take some time (5-10 seconds) and it doesn't make sense to return the user to the normal UI while it's doing it, so I want to present a view letting the user know what the progress is.

From one VC, I use Dropbox's drop-in file picker, then load up a presented (modal VC) thus:

```
        ZSImportVC *importVC = [[ZSImportVC alloc] init];
        importVC.results = results;
        [importVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
        [self presentViewController:importVC animated:YES completion:^{
            [self performFetch];
        }];
```

The VC (a bog-standard UIViewController), has a UILabel property:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusMessage;
```

In viewWillAppear: I can set the text of this label without any problem. The thing is, I want to keep changing this text as the process of manipulating the file continues.

The method that manipulates the file is called from viewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self processImport];
}
```

However, within the processImport method, the following has no effect:

```
self.statusMessage.text = @"Some text to update the user.";
```

So I created a method:

```
- (IBAction)updateStatus:(NSString *)message
{
    [self.statusMessage setText:message];
    NSLog(@"%@", message);
}
```

just to check what's going on. The NSLog shows that the method is being called okay, but the label text doesn't change. I tried adding:

```
[self.statusMessage setNeedsDisplay];
```

to the method, but that didn't help. I'm not using any private queues or background threads. I read somewhere that using NSNotification helps, so I tried adding this to viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateStatus:) name:@"updateStatus" object:nil];
```

Then changed the called method to:

```
- (void)updateStatus:(NSNotification *)message
{
    [self.statusMessage setText:message.object];
    NSLog(@"%@", message.object);
}
```

and called this from the main method with:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateStatus" object:@"Retrieving file from Dropbox" userInfo:nil];
```

I could see from the console messages that the updateStatus method is getting called, but still the text doesn't change. Clearly I'm missing something here. Any thoughts?

Comment: check the linkage from `styoryboard` to your `UILabel`. does it link properly?

Comment: Are you able to add more complete code? I want to know from where you addObserver, postNotificationName and etc.. Then may be I can simulate the process on my side.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at the place you're setting the text, what is the output of `po self.statusMessage`? Also, in that context, what thread is it being called on? (in the left navigator)

Comment: HelmiB: I'm not using a storyboard. The UILabel is linked fine. I can set it in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear. I just can't change it at any point thereafter...

Comment: Everything appears to be running on Thread 1. The _statusMessage property is getting updated, but its changed value is not being shown on the view.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `ZSImportVC` instances on Debug perspective.

I think u are sending `[self.statusMessage setText:message.object];`
to another instance, that it is not shown on the screen.

I mean,

put a debug point here:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self processImport];     /* Debug point here*/
}
```

and check what´s the hexadecimal direction for `self`.

Now , do the same here:

```
- (void)updateStatus:(NSNotification *)message
{
    [self.statusMessage setText:message.object];  /* Debug point here*/
    NSLog(@"%@", message.object);
}
```

Btw, I had some problems with

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateStatus" object:@"Retrieving file from Dropbox" userInfo:nil];
```

because the instance that receive this notification was not the correct.

I fixed that calling a normal method, but u maybe could not do that.

Sorry for my english :S

Comment: self remains constant throughout - eg: <ZSImportVC: 0x146d8b00> - I checked it in several other places too.

Comment: Try this:  `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateLabel:) withObject:yourString waitUntilDone:YES];`  `updateLabel` is a normal method, not an IBAction. With this u are forcing to update your label on the main thread. Else we can try another thing.

Comment: Tried that, but no change.